# MySql Query (Brain Challenge)

Tags: mysql, sql

List all aircraft that have three or more servicing jobs done within the last three months (90 Days). Also, List all aircraft registration number, plane_type, and manufacturer.

Pilot Table:

```
 reg_nbr, plane_type, manufacturer, resident, date_service
'101', 'SE Prop', 'Lear', '1', '1998-12-01'
'202', 'DE Prop', 'Cessna', '1', '1999-11-22'
'303', 'SE Jet', 'Bombardier', '1', '2000-07-06'
'404', 'ME Jet', 'Lear', '1', '2001-02-24'
'505', 'SE Prop', 'Cessna', '0', '2003-12-01'
'606', 'DE Prop', 'Bombardier', '1', '2004-11-22'
'707', 'SE Jet', 'Lear', '1', '2005-07-06'
'808', 'ME Jet', 'Cessna', '0', '2005-02-24'
'909', 'SE Prop', 'Bombardier', '1', '2002-02-12'
```

Services Table:

```
workorder_nbr, file_nbr, reg_nbr, date_start, date_end, work_description, hours_worked, person_nbr
'2061', '3101', '101', '2014-03-16', '2014-03-16', 'Maint', '2', '901'
'2062', '3101', '101', '2014-07-20', '2014-07-21', 'Maint', '3', '901'
'2063', '3102', '202', '2015-12-22', '2015-12-22', 'Replace', '5', '901'
'2064', '3102', '202', '2015-07-12', '2015-07-13', 'Clean', '2', '901'
'2065', '3103', '303', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-01', 'Maint', '2', '901'
'2066', '3104', '404', '2015-07-09', '2015-07-09', 'Clean', '5', '901'
'2067', '3108', '505', '2015-07-09', '2015-07-09', 'Maint', '2', '901'
'2068', '3106', '606', '2015-08-21', '2015-08-21', 'Check', '1', '901'
'2069', '3101', '101', '2016-01-15', '2016-01-16', 'Maint', '3', '901'
'2070', '3101', '101', '2016-01-31', '2016-01-31', 'Repair', '15', '901'
'2071', '3101', '101', '2016-02-08', '2016-02-10', 'Repair', '8', '901'
'2072', '3108', '505', '2016-01-08', '2016-01-09', 'Upgrade', '20', '901'
'2073', '3108', '505', '2016-02-02', '2016-02-02', 'Repair', '1', '901'
'2074', '3108', '505', '2014-02-11', '2014-02-11', 'Maint', '1', '901'
```

My Query: (Its wrong anyways)

```
SELECT service.reg_nbr, plane_type, manufacturer
FROM service, aircraft
WHERE date_start BETWEEN (date(NOW() AND 90DAY)
GROUP BY service.reg_nbr
HAVING COUNT(service.reg_nbr) >=3
```

I am struggling in WHERE clase that how to make it show current date to 90 days back as required by the question)

Comment: Just asking to be sure, but in your real query do you have the join condition in place? Your current example will produce an implicit cross join resulting in the Cartesian product between *service* and *aircraft*.

Comment: Buddy, two tables should be joined and it doesn't matter how. 
Can you please tell me how to show only those aircrafts that appeared at least 3 or more times? thanks

Comment: I'm not your buddy, pal. How they're joined matters greatly. Your query joins every row from table *service* to every row from table *aircraft*. This could be what you want, but I doubt it. See the accepted answer, which now uses an explicit join and has the join condition `a.reg_nbr = s.reb_nbr`. It is equivalent to a natural join, as `reg_nbr` is the only common attribute.

Comment: I highly recommend that you read ["JOIN syntax"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) documentation, which displays the myriad of ways you can perform a join.

Comment: Yeah! I saw it and its working. Thanks for you effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `INTERVAL`:

```
WHERE date_start BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT s.reg_nbr
FROM aircraft a
INNER JOIN service s
    ON a.reg_nbr = s.reg_nbr
WHERE date_start BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY s.reg_nbr
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Just to confirm that no aircrafts will be displayed because in service table as there is no such aircraft which has 3 or more service jobs and also with range of today to 90 day back? or does the question mean to display aircrafts who had servicing jobs 3 or more and within their first 90 days? Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Replace your `WHERE` clause with my answer to restrict to the last 90 days of data in your table.  `WHERE` gets applied before `GROUP BY` happens, which is what you want.

Comment: Yes I did it its working buddy. Can you tell me how to show only those  aircraft that got serviced at least 3 and more '> =' . It is there in the question. Thanks and you deserve the accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use DATE_ADD function :

```
SELECT service.reg_nbr, plane_type, manufacturer
FROM service, aircraft
WHERE date_start BETWEEN date(NOW()) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -90 DAY)
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: its causing error sonique but anyways thanks for effort